# Draw Text in Middle of the Screen

Tags: java, string, swing, java-2d, fontmetrics

I'm trying to draw text in the middle of my JFrame window, and it's off by a little bit.

Here's what I've tried :

```
FontMetrics fontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);

// draw title
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g.setFont(font);
int titleLen = fontMetrics.stringWidth("Level 1 Over!");
g.drawString("Level 1 Over!", (screenWidth / 2) - (titleLen / 2), 80);
```

Comment: How are you setting the value of the screenWidth variable?

Comment: The screenWidth variable is actually renamed, because it's actually GamePanel.WIDTH. That variable is the int that the JFrame's Width is determined from.

Comment: Does your JFrame have decorations? You may have to care about the Insets of the JFrame then.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW - Instead of painting in a top level container such as `JFrame`, add a `JPanel` & do custom painting in the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.  Also return a sensible preferred size for the custom component, to assist the layout manager.  Then center the text according to the size of the **custom container** rather than the screen.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that the TextLayout class gives better dimensions for the String than FontMetrics.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (font == null) {
        return;
    }

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    FontRenderContext frc = g2d.getFontRenderContext();
    TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(sampleString, font, frc);
    Rectangle2D bounds = layout.getBounds();

    int width = (int) Math.round(bounds.getWidth());
    int height = (int) Math.round(bounds.getHeight());
    int x = (getWidth() - width) / 2;
    int y = height + (getHeight() - height) / 2;

    layout.draw(g2d, (float) x, (float) y);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With your code, the String starts at the very middle. try this:

```
FontMetrics fontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);

// draw title
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g.setFont(font);
int titleLen = fontMetrics.stringWidth("Level 1 Over!");
g.drawString("Level 1 Over!", (screenWidth / 2) - (titleLen), 80);
```

Comment: No, that still doesn't work. I don't understand it, it seems like it would work.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but this worked for me...

```
public void drawCenter ( String m , Font font )
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics ( font );
    int sw = fm.stringWidth ( m );
    g.setFont ( font );
    g.setColor ( Color.BLACK );
    g.drawString ( m , ( frame.getWidth() + sw ) / 2 - sw , frame.getHeight() / 2 );
}
```

In this example g is Graphics2D but I think it works with Graphics also

Answer (score 0):

**-** Use `Toolkit` to get the **height** and **width** of the screen.

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();
```

**-** Then set the text in the middle of the screen.

```
g.drawString("Level 1 Over!",(width/2),(height/2));
```

Comment: That's going to start the text at the middle of the screen. The OP's code is an attempt to centre the text in the screen, not centre the first letter.